# Proxychains work and dont work with tor

Tags: networking, proxy, tor

Everything works smoothly until I look up on google "Whats my ip"
and it actually shows my real IPv4, but only when I go to other websites to track my ip everything works very well. Another thing that's to be noted is I have tor running (I ran tor with `sudo service tor start` and it ran fine)

I have dynamic set in proxychains.conf
and here's what the end of proxychains.conf:

```
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
```

which I have ran through the TOR port (9050)

If someone could help me it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to configure your browser's proxy settings in a proper way. The proxy type will be socks4 (you can try socks5 too if it doesn't work) set the ip to local host (127.0.0.1) and to port 9050. But 'make sure' you make these configurations through the browser interface. For other tools that don't have a proxy configuration interface, you can use proxychains.